# How to do the following projection in Matlab?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, normed-spaces

I have 2 vectors $u$ and $v$  given in $\mathbb R^4$, e.g. $u = (-1,-2,3,4)$ and $v=(1,-2,-3,5)$
I also have $Ax=b$ which is an under-determined system; meaning, if $A$ is $m\times n$, then $m\le n$.

We define a 2 dimensional plane as follows $K=\{x\in \mathbb R^4:\, u^Tx = 1,\,v^Tx = 1\}$.

**I need to find the projection of some point $z = (1,2,2,1)$ on $K$ plane by formulating a least-norm problem.**

I know that I can use $x=A'(AA')^{-1}\setminus b$ this formula to solve the least-norm problem.

Thanks

Comment: If $m > n$ then your system is overdtermined, not underdetermined (assuming $A$ has full rank).  Also, note that Matlab's backslash operator automatically computes least squares solutions to overdetermined systems.

Comment: i meant m<n, mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \text{proj}_K(z) - z$.  Then $x$ is the vector of least norm such that $z + x$ belongs to $K$.  You can now find a least norm solution to the system of two equations that must be satisfied by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $K$ is equivalent to the solutions $x$ of
$Ax=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}u^T\\v^T\end{bmatrix}$.

$x$ can then be calculated in MATLAB with

```
x=A/b
```

This will be the projection onto the plane, with $b$ defined as $b=[1,1]^T$.

Comment: How does this solution use $z$?

Comment: @littleO It is not a full solution. It simplifies (depending on the OP's level) the set which the projection lies on. The projection must lie in the affine space $x_p+\mathcal{N}(A)$, where $x_p$ is a particular solution of the linear system. At this point, you introduce $z$ to find the projection.